# Flutter widget background not fill screen

Tags: flutter

I want to use a widget with a background color that only occupy a specific space without expanding for full screen. But, if I try this with Container it doesn't work like I want:

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
    ),
),
```

This code occupy the full screen, instead of only using the size it needs.

The idea is to show a Text and a Button in a Column, with a white background color. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: show full code please, it is hard to answer if you do not provide info on your `BuildContext` on your `Container`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I not really understand with your question, but you can wrap container inside container, and add padding in it. Or you can use stack to make your design more dynamic.

here is my code: maybe as you wish

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            color: Colors.green
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Text 1'),
              FlatButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Button1"))
            ],
          ),
        )
    ),
  )
```

hope this can help you, thank you

Comment: I tried this one, but doing like this make the view occupy all height of the screen (instead of just the piece it needs)

Comment: just add new widget upside the container,.. That is SingleChildScrollView,, learn for more of it,, it will really help you about list, column etc..